# Give label an Anchor (<a>) tag to a ASP Label that directs to a certain View

Tags: asp.net

I have a question about which I could not find an answer to.

I basically want to give certain parts of the label a link, so when the user clicks on it it directs to a certain view from the multiview using for example:

```
MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 6;
```

This is how a label is build:

```
Caractere > -9
```

The word "Caractere" directs to a different view than "-9".

So my question here is:

Is this even possible? And if so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Labels cannot have  tags inside them

I would recommend you to create a user control with label and link controls based on your requirement

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Could you maybe elaborate on what you mean? Maybe give an example of code that should work?